# Will the second layout UI overwrite the first layout UI in android Studio?

Tags: android

The following sample code is from https://github.com/android/camera/tree/master/CameraXBasic.

In CameraFragment.kt, the system load fragment_camera.xml layout UI first, then load camera_ui_container.xml layout UI.

Will the second layout UI overwrite the first layout UI in android Studio? In my mind, the fragment_camera.xml will be hidden, right?

**[CameraFragment.kt](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt)**

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false)



override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      ...
      updateCameraUi()
 }


private fun updateCameraUi() {

    // Remove previous UI if any
    container.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.camera_ui_container)?.let {
        container.removeView(it)
    }

    // Inflate a new view containing all UI for controlling the camera
    val controls = View.inflate(requireContext(), R.layout.camera_ui_container, container)
  ...
```

}

**fragment_camera.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/camera_container"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/view_finder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**camera_ui_container.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Camera control and gallery buttons -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/camera_switch_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xlarge"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_switch"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gallery_button_alt" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/camera_capture_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_large"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_large"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/shutter_button_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_shutter"
        android:contentDescription="@string/capture_button_alt"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/photo_view_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xlarge"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_outer_circle"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/switch_camera_button_alt" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: No, it's just inflating `camera_ui_container` into the `Fragment`'s `ConstraintLayout`. The `<TextureView>` will remain.

Answer (score 0):

No, `inflate()` doesn't mean it will be added into fragment's UI, `inflate()` is used to convert layout xml into `View`.

So you will need to add both of them inside your fragments layout and make one of them hidden first, then hide another one when you want to show another.

or add or remove them from fragment's UI dynamically.

**Example :**

Code in XML File :

```
<RelativeLayout>

<camera_ui_container> --> set visibility to gone
<camera_container> --> set visibility to visible

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code in Fragment.java :

when you want to show `camera_ui_container` :

```
camera_ui_container.setVisibility(VISIBLE)
camera_container.setVisibility(GONE)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't find such as the code `camera_ui_container.setVisibility(VISIBLE)` in the project.

Comment: It is just an idea, you will need to implement it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks! but in the project CameraXBasic, it seems that the system display the two layout UI simultaneously.